# SimpleDateformat and "Day of week in month" (F)

Tags: java

I would like to get which day of the week is the current day and looking the SimpleDateFormat class I tought that the "F" is what I need. So I wrote a little test:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("F").format(new Date()));
```

Today is wednesday and I expect to get 3 as output. Instead I get 2.

As english isn't my mothertongue, did I missunderstand the meaning of the format?

Comment: in the question you're talking about "F" and your code has "E"

Comment: Fixed. I just tried with E to see if I get the right day and left the E by copy&Paste...

Comment: Did you know some countries start counting from Sunday ? make sure your code is as global as it needs to be.

Comment: I tried the same yesterday and run the same today to see if it was a problem of 0 to 6 or Sunday as first day. Yestarday I got 2 too...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`F` - Day of week in month

`E` -  Day name in week

try `u` - Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)

Note that 'u' is since Java 7, but if you need just day number of the week then use Calendar

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

You can change first day of week by changing Locale or directly as

```
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

Answer (score 18):

Today is the second Wednesday in the current month.

Comment: excellent! that's finally cleared it up for me :-) I guess this is good for determining some particular holidays, or events occurring, like our company update, every first monday of the month :-)

Comment: I have to downvote this, as today is actually the first Tuesday in the current month.  (I'll return in eight days to vote back up!)

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Calendar/.Date and related classes are a confusing mess as you have learned the hard way. Counting from zero for month numbers and day-of-week numbers is one of many poor design choices made in those old classes.

## java.time

Those old classes have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `DayOfWeek`

For day of week, use the well-named [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

If you want an integer for day-of-week compliant with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) where Monday = 1 and Sunday = 7, you can extract that from an instance of `DayOfWeek`.

### Conversion

If starting with a java.util.Calendar object, convert to java.time.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilCalendarObject.toInstant();
```

Apply a time zone in order to get a date in order to get a day-of-week.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zdt.getDayOfWeek();
```

Note that time zone in crucial in determining a date, and therefore a day-of-week. The date is not the same around the world simultaneously. A new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal, for example.

### Number Of Day-Of-Week

Now that we have java.time and this enum built into Java, I suggest you freely pass around those enum instances rather than a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

But if you insist on an integer, ask the `DayOfWeek`.

```
int dayOfWeekNumber = dayOfWeek.getValue();
```

### String Of Day-Of-Week

That enum generates a localized String for the name of the day-of-week.

```
String output = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Or Locale.ENGLISH.
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexes for the days of week start from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
F -> Day of week in month(1-5)
```

Today is - `09/01/2013(dd/MM/yyyy)` which fall 2nd in week so it has printed 2.

If you try with `16/01/2013` then it would print 3.

Answer (score 1):

**F = Day of Week in Month**
**1day** to **7day**, it will print **1**.
**8day** to **14day**, it will print **2**.
**15day** to **21day**, it will print **3**.
**22day** to **28day**, it will print **4** and
**29day** to **31day**, it will print **5**.

Answer (score 0):

just use this method for this.

```
public String day(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEE", new Locale("tr", "TR"));
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```